# my android countdowntimer only fires onFinish() if I pass countDownTime as parameter.

Tags: android, parameter-passing, countdowntimer

**my CountdownTimer Class**

```
private class AutoStartCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public AutoStartCountDownTimer(long millisUntilFinished, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisUntilFinished, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        log("timer finish..");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        log("some task");
    }

}
```

**This class I am calling from activity's onCreate() method**

```
new AutoStartCountDownTimer(remainingTime, 1000).start();
```

This call directly executes onFinish() of my timer class

**But now if call the same class in following way, it simply runs fine for 30 second.**

```
new AutoStartCountDownTimer(30000, 1000).start();
```

this is really strange and i am also not getting any systematic help form anywhere.

my target SDK version is 19

Comment: This is because your remaining time is less than or equal to 1000. Probably it's in second and you forgot to convert it to ms.

Comment: my remaining time is 69836000 (around 115 hours)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the onTick and onFinish method inside the counter. It worked for me
. I am using a countdowntimer in my recent app .
Here's my code ,  maybe it will help

```
aCounter = new CountDownTimer(total_duration, duration) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            log("some task");
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            log("timer finish..");
        }
    };
    aCounter.start();
```